# Data saved as "[object%20object]" in my Firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, google-cloud-firestore

Whenever I tried to register in SignUp.js, in the region section, it will be saved as "object Object" in my Firestore:

[image: firestore database]

In sign up, user have to choose the state and region, I fetched the state and region using an API, however, when I clicked sign up button, only state is registered correctly in my Firestore. For region, it become `"[object%20object]"`

Below is my SignUp.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
import { app } from "../firebase";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { setDoc, doc, addDoc, collection } from "firebase/firestore";
import { ToastContainer, toast } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
import { TextInput, Label, Checkbox, Button } from "flowbite-react";

const SignUp = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [email, setEmail] = useState(null);
  const [masjidname, setMasjidName] = useState(null);
  const [password, setPassword] = useState(null);
  const [confirmpassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState(null);
  const [load, setLoad] = useState(true);
  const [username, setUsername] = useState(null);
  const [region, setRegion] = useState([]);
  const [states,setStates]=useState([])
  const [selectedstate,setSelectedState]=useState([]);
  const [regions,setRegions]=useState([])
  const [showregions,setShowRegions]=useState([])
  const auth = getAuth(app);

  const signup = () => {
    if (password === confirmpassword) {
      const e = email;
      const p = password;
      createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, e, p)
        .then((userCredential) => {
          const user = userCredential.user;
          user.displayName = masjidname;
          const db = getFirestore(app);
          const storage = getStorage(app);
          const setuser = async () => {
            const db = getFirestore(app);
            let docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "Users"), {
              email: user.email,
              MasjidName: masjidname,
              Username: username,
              state:selectedstate,
              region: region,
            });
          };
          setuser();
          toast.success("Mosque Registered !");
          setTimeout(function () {
            navigate("/");
          }, 1800);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          toast.error("Please fill in all forms");
          const errorCode = error.code;
          const errorMessage = error.message;
        });
    }
  };
  const changeconfirmpassword = (e) => {
    setConfirmPassword(e.target.value);
    setLoad(!load);
  };
  const changeemail = (e) => {
    setEmail(e.target.value);
    setLoad(!load);
  };
  const changemasjidname = (e) => {
    setMasjidName(e.target.value);
    setLoad(!load);
  };
  const changepassword = (e) => {
    setPassword(e.target.value);
    setLoad(!load);
  };
  const changeusername = (e) => {
    setUsername(e.target.value);
    setLoad(!load);
  };
  const changeregion = (e) => {
    setRegion(e.target.value);
    setLoad(!load);
    console.log(region);
  };
  const changestate=(e)=>{
         setSelectedState(states[e.target.value])
         setShowRegions(regions[e.target.value])
  }



  useEffect(()=>{
    
    axios.get("https://waktu-solat-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/prayer_times.json")
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response.data.data.negeri)
      var nameArray = response.data.data.negeri.map(function (el) { return el.nama; });
      var regions = response.data.data.negeri.map(function (el) { return el.zon; });
      setStates(nameArray)
      setRegions(regions)
      setShowRegions(regions[0])
    })
    .catch(function (error) { console.log(error); })
    .finally(function () { });

  },[])
  return (
    <div className="min-h-screen bg-gradient-to-r from-[#02062a] to-[#343857]   py-4 ">
      <div className="lg:flex  sm:block lg:px-40  sm:px-5">
        <div className="w-2/3  mx-auto ">
          <ToastContainer
            position="top-center"
            autoClose={1000}
            hideProgressBar={false}
            newestOnTop={false}
            closeOnClick
            rtl={false}
            pauseOnFocusLoss
            draggable
            pauseOnHover
            theme="dark"
          />
          <h1 className="text-white text-xl font-semibold">
            <img
              src="./LogoDashMasjid.png"
              alt=""
              className="inline-block w-[50px]"
            />
            <Link className="text-transparent bg-clip-text bg-gradient-to-t from-[#E1C49A] to-amber-200" to={"/"}>
              DASHMASJID
            </Link>
          </h1>
          <div className="justify-center text-white mt-12">
            <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold">
              Welcome, to{" "}
              <span class="font-bold text-transparent bg-clip-text bg-gradient-to-t from-[#E1C49A] to-amber-200">
                DashMasjid.
              </span>
            </h1>

            <h1 className="my-2 mb-10 mt-3">
              Please enter your details
            </h1>
            <form className=" flex-col gap-2">
              {/* USERNAME */}
              <div className="mb-2 block">
                <Label
                  htmlFor="email"
                  value="Your Username"
                  className="text-white font-bold"
                />
              </div>

              <TextInput
                id="text"
                type="text"
                sizing="md"
                onChange={changeusername}
                value={username}
                placeholder="Username"
                className="sm:w-full my-3 lg:w-1/2"
                required={true}
              />

              {/* <label htmlFor="email" className="text-[10px] font-bold">
                USERNAME
              </label>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="username"
                onChange={changeusername}
                value={username}
                placeholder="Username"
                className="text-black block my-3 sm:w-full lg:w-1/2 rounded-3xl px-3 py-2 bg-gray-200 border-none"
                id=""
              /> */}

              {/* MASJIDNAME */}

              <Label
                htmlFor="mosquename"
                value="Mosque's Name"
                className="text-white font-bold"
              />

              <TextInput
                id="mosquename"
                type="text"
                sizing="md"
                onChange={changemasjidname}
                value={masjidname}
                placeholder="Mosque's name"
                className="sm:w-full my-3 lg:w-1/2"
                required={true}
              />

              {/* <label htmlFor="email" className="text-[10px] font-bold">
              MASJIDNAME
            </label>
            <input
              type="email"
              name="email"
              onChange={changemasjidname}
              value={masjidname}
              placeholder="Masjid name"
              className="text-black block my-3 sm:w-full lg:w-1/2 rounded-3xl px-3 py-2 bg-gray-200 border-none"
              id=""
            /> */}

              {/* EMAIL */}

              <Label
                htmlFor="email"
                value="Your Email"
                className="text-white font-bold"
              />

              <TextInput
                id="email"
                type="email"
                sizing="md"
                onChange={changeemail}
                value={email}
                placeholder="dashmasjid@gmail.com"
                className="sm:w-full my-3 lg:w-1/2"
                required={true}
              />

              {/* <label htmlFor="email" className="text-[10px] font-bold">
              EMAIL
            </label>
            <input
              type="email"
              name="email"
              onChange={changeemail}
              value={email}
              placeholder="dashmasjid@gmail.com"
              className="text-black block my-3 sm:w-full lg:w-1/2 rounded-3xl px-3 py-2 bg-gray-200 border-none"
              id=""
            /> */}
              {/* State */}

              <Label
                htmlFor="state"
                value="State"
                className="text-white font-bold"
              />
              <select required={true}
                onChange={(e)=>{changestate(e)}}
                className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500 sm:w-full my-3 lg:w-1/2"

              >
              {
                states.map((item,index)=>{
                  return(
                    index==0?<option value={index} selected>{item}</option>: <option value={index}>{item}</option>
                  )
                })
              }
              </select>

              {/* REGION */}

              <Label
                htmlFor="region"
                value="Region"
                className="text-white font-bold"
              />
              <select required={true}
                onChange={changeregion}
                className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500 sm:w-full my-3 lg:w-1/2"

              >
              {
                showregions.map((item,index)=>{
                  return(
                    index==0?<option value={item.nama} selected>{item.nama}</option>: <option value={item}>{item.nama}</option>
                  )
                })
              }
             
              </select>

              {/* PASSWORD */}

              <Label
                htmlFor="password"
                value="Your password"
                className="text-white font-bold"
              />
              <TextInput
                id="password"
                name="password"
                type="password"
                onChange={changepassword}
                value={password}
                placeholder="Password"
                required={true}
                className="sm:w-full my-3 lg:w-1/2"
              />

              {/* <label htmlFor="email" className="text-[10px] font-bold">
              PASSWORD
            </label>
            <input
              type="password"
              name="password"
              onChange={changepassword}
              value={password}
              placeholder="Password"
              className="text-black block my-3 sm:w-full lg:w-1/2 rounded-3xl px-3 py-2 bg-gray-200 border-none"
              id=""
            /> */}

              {/* COMFIRMPASSWORD */}
              <Label
                htmlFor="compassword"
                value="Comfirm password"
                className="text-white font-bold"
              />
              <TextInput
                id="password"
                name="password"
                type="password"
                onChange={changeconfirmpassword}
                value={confirmpassword}
                placeholder="Comfirm Password"
                required={true}
                className="sm:w-full my-3 lg:w-1/2"
              />
            </form>

            {/* <label htmlFor="email" className="text-[10px] font-bold">
              CONFIRMPASSWORD
            </label>
            <input
              type="password"
              name="password"
              onChange={changeconfirmpassword}
              value={confirmpassword}
              placeholder="Confrim Password"
              className="text-black block my-3 sm:w-full lg:w-1/2 rounded-3xl px-3 py-2 bg-gray-200 border-none"
              id=""
            /> */}

            {/* BUTTON */}
            &nbsp;
            <Button
              onClick={signup}
              className="text-white bg-gradient-to-br from-purple-600 to-blue-500 hover:bg-gradient-to-bl focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 shadow-lg shadow-blue-500/50 dark:shadow-lg dark:shadow-blue-800/80 dark:focus:ring-blue-800 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm sm:w-full my-3 lg:w-1/2"

            >
              Sign up
            </Button>
            <h2 className="text-gray-300 text-center lg:w-1/2 sm:w-full">
              Already have an account?
              <span> </span>
              <Link className="font-bold text-transparent bg-clip-text bg-gradient-to-t from-[#E1C49A] to-amber-200" to={"/signin"}>
                Sign in
              </Link>
            </h2>

          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="mx-auto lg:w-1/2 sm:w-0 ">
          <img
            src="./LogoDashMasjid.png"
            width={550}
            height={550}
            className="mx-auto mt-[180px]"
            alt=""
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SignUp;
```

I have tried to use chatGPT to fix this, the problem still persist. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

This scenario occurs when you have a destination format of string but you provide an object, this can also be an array which is what appears to be the case in your state management of `region`. A common example of this is trying to render an object inside of an `alert()` window. It will simply print `[object%20object]` as it can't parse the passed value.

Are you using an ODM? or have you pre-configured the types of each field within your collections?

Ensure that you are delivering the correct data type to update your region, which in this case, the logical answer would be a string.

The first thing I would change would be:

```
// const [region, setRegion] = useState([]); // OLD
const [region, setRegion] = useState(""); // NEW
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  const [region, setRegion] = useState([]);
```

Why do you use `[]` in this situation? I think it should be `""` instead of `[]`.
Then when you don't select a region, what should be submitted to the server?